# sql bulk insert quoted comma delimited values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the follwing txt file with quoted comma delimted file

```
"col1","Col2","col3","col4","col4","col5","col6","col7"
"text for col1","123 NW St, Suite 23",,,"12345","AZ"
```

I would have no problem with this, except sometimes in the street address has a comma, then bulk insert thinks it's a new column.  then with empty records/values there are no quotes.  I have seen some examples using the with format file.  How wold I use a format file for this type of file?

```
bulk insert #temptbl
from 'C:\test\Test.txt' 
with (FORMATFILE='C:\test\formattest.txt',rowterminator='\n')
```

I also want to add, those empty filed when they have values, they have quotes.

Comment: Perfect, this was what I was looking for!  Tested and works!

Comment: sorry about the duplicate post.